# JPL Java Prolog Query fails

Tags: java, prolog

I have the following Prolog files:
(`clauses.qa2.pl`)

```
get(mary,milk,1).
go(john,bedroom,1).
go(sandra,kitchen,1).
go(mary,hallway,1).
get(john,football,1).
go(john,hallway,2).
drop(john,football,2).
go(mary,garden,2).
go(john,kitchen,3).
```

and (`rules.pl`)

```
/*This rule finds last location of a person */
isAt(X,Y) :- go(X, Y, T), \+ (go(X,_,T2), T2 > T).

/* This rule finds the last location of an object */
whereIs(Q,R) :- findall(R,(get(P,Q,I),go(P,R,_)),L), last(L,R),!.
```

along with the following java code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import jpl.*;
import java.io.*;
import jpl.Query;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrologTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        //include the prolog file with clauses to test
        File clauseFile = new File ("C:\\Natural_Language_Final_Project\\PrologTest\\src\\clauses_qa2.pl");
        File ruleFile = new File ("C:\\Natural_Language_Final_Project\\PrologTest\\src\\rules.pl");
        String clausePath = clauseFile.getAbsolutePath();
        String rulePath = ruleFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Clause file path: " + clausePath);
        System.out.println("Rule file path: " + rulePath);
        Query q1 = new Query("consult",new Term[]{new Atom("C:\\Natural_Language_Final_Project\\PrologTest\\src\\clauses_qa2.pl")});
        Query q2 = new Query("consult",new Term[]{new Atom("C:\\Natural_Language_Final_Project\\PrologTest\\src\\rules.pl")});
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(ruleFile);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
        
        
        jpl.JPL.init();
        
        
        Variable X = new Variable("X");
        Variable Y = new Variable ("Y");
        Query q = new Query(new Compound("isAt",new Term[]{new Atom("john"),X}));
                                                            

            Hashtable solution = q.oneSolution();
            System.out.println( "X = " + solution.get("X"));
```

}

The java code, given the Prolog should return `X = kitchen`. Instead, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" jpl.PrologException: PrologException:
>
> error(existence_error(procedure, /(isAt, 3)), context(:(system, /('$c_call_prolog', 0)), _0))
>
> at jpl.Query.get1(Query.java:336)
>
> at jpl.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:258)
>
> at jpl.Query.oneSolution(Query.java:688)
>
> at PrologTest.main(PrologTest.java:43)

Any ideas on how to correct this?